Send Input to Interactive Process via File Descriptor
How can I find the file descriptor that a process reads input from?
Background
I run a Vite (pronounced veet) server when developing in an Alpine container. Currently I login to the container and manually start Vite with the command vite --host '0.0.0.0' --port 3000, it takes over the console and allows input interactively. So I can do things like restart the server when file changes don't register on the Docker volume bind mount in the container (Windows being silly).
Problem
I would like to have the container run this command on startup. When I do I lose the ability to send commands as Docker does not pass them along.

I then made a script that runs pnpm run dev &; thinking I could get the process ID of the Vite server, then send input to that file descriptor with echo "h" > /proc/17/fd/0, but nothing happens. I also tried PID 33. I assumed that I'm sending input to the wrong place. But How can I find the correct file descriptor, if there is any.
PS output in container
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 node /usr/local/bin/pnpm run dev
   17 root      0:00 node /root/task-01/node_modules/.bin/../vite/bin/vite.js --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
   33 root      0:00 /root/task-01/node_modules/.pnpm/@esbuild+linux-x64@0.20.2/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild --service=0.20.
   39 root      0:00 sh
   47 root      0:00 ps

Disclaimer: This should now be solved with Docker watch since I will no longer need to manually restart the server when files change; but I want to see if its possible as this can be useful for other cases. Also, don't shame me for running as root, I don't normally do that.
